# Ext.net PageProxy: what is it and how does it work?

Tags: ext.net

I found that PageProxy can be used to get data from page, but I don't understand what does it mean exaclty and what's the difference with HttpProxy.
In particular:

- who/when starts the request?
- how does the request interact with the page life cycle?
- where does the data come from? There is no url property on PageProxy.
  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First see the following sample
http://examples1.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Paging_and_Sorting/Page/

If you use PageProxy then you have to set OnRefreshData event handler in the store